# Should I return the posted data from the back-end after it was posted? ANGULAR + NODEJS

Tags: node.js, angular, post, crud

I have a straightforward question.
Inside my Angular & NodeJS & MySQL app, I have a FORM where the user add's hes workers, after each worker add, the info posted to the back-end and the user can see a preview with all the info that he just been posted plus he can delete each worker from the this preview.  Now I have two options

**OPTION ONE** (currently using) - Get only the Id of the created worker from the back end and push it with the created values to an Array of workers.
this way I am avoiding using a complex SELECT query that should return the data from 3 different tables inside the POST route. BUT I don't display the actual data from the back-end.

**OPTION TWO**  - Return all the values after each post and push the returned values inside the workers Array for the preview. This way I display the actual data from the server BUT I must return the data from the POST method and use a complex query as I mention in option one.

Any suggestions what is the best practice will be appreciated
I don't adding any code because its irrelevant.

Comment: If the shape of the data is the same as you'd get from the server, minus the ID, there's no reason to return the result of the call, since you already have all of the data client-side, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you shouldn't return the data after a POST request. At least according to the [HTTP standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). You should only return the URL for the resource you just created in the [Location header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location).

Let's say you created a new `User` using `POST /users`. Then in the response you should have a **status code 201 (created)** and in the location header the URL to the resource. For example `/users/1234` where the `1234` part is the ID of the user.

Answer (score 0):

you should return the posted data along with status code of 201 that's one of many rules of the REST API i recommend you to take look at [this article](https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9) it explains REST API  designing guidelines